# How can I add a messaging sub-app to my Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I basically just want users to be able to interact with each other, thread style. Is there a gem or a plugin that will accomplish this for me, or must I roll my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ryan bates has a screen cast, http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry. He uses the ancestry gem to create a threaded comment system.